# Order in junit classes

Tags: java, junit, static

I have a static class with two methods. One check the state and the other modifies it.
In all my test classes I need to use the method who modifies, and all it's ok.
But I want to test the initial case to call the "checkState" method before any "modify" call. Then, I create a test class with this test.
If I run only this class, all it's ok, and the methods run fine. But if I run all the test classes in the application, this methods fail, I think it's because the other test classes calls the modify static method before.

There is someway to control the order of the test classes (not methods)?

Comment: You need to post some (relevant) code in order to help you. But you should mock your values or using reflection some how in order to make the test results independents of other test runs.

Comment: Looks like your tests depend on other tests, it is best to avoid dependency between tests. Try creating a new object of the state class in setUp method of each test class.

Comment: I know that it's a bad solution, but I need to work with a terrible architecture with no sense, and I want to work as best that I could with it.